# until, until after and quote from 1984

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> **Until** they become conscious they will never rebel, and **until after** they have rebelled they cannot become conscious.

*Until they become conscious they will never rebel.* Is this part meaning that 
if they became conscious, they will rebel?

second part: they rebelled but it doesn't matter because they didn't do it consciously?

This part of *1984* is a bit tricky for me and I want to understand it properly.

Comment: If they became conscious, they **would** rebel, but they will not rebel, because in order to do that they have to be conscious already. There is a circle in the conditions which makes the rebellion unlikely.

Comment: until after they have rebelled they cannot become conscious. but this part means that to start rebellion they have to be conscius? why is this part in present perfect?

Comment: I'm sorry for being a bit imprecise—the second part means they can obtain consciousness only **after** rebellion: they have to have rebelled to get consciousness... but they will not, because.... and so on.

Comment: No A until B, but B only if A - that's the scheme.

Answer (score 2):

> Until they become conscious they will never rebel, and until after they have rebelled they cannot become conscious.

The sentence is describing how the people are "caught" in a loop that they cannot get out of.

> *Until they become conscious they will never rebel*

essentially says:

> They can't rebel now, because they are not conscious yet. (People who are unaware of a good reason to start a rebellion generally won't rebel).

Then:

> *and until after they have rebelled they cannot become conscious*.

essentially means:

> They will stay in their "unconscious" state until a rebellion breaks out.

Ergo, they are stuck.

It's worth noting that *unconscious* in this context means "unaware of their miserable existence, as if in a stupor." It doesn't mean the people have fainted or passed out.

NOAD defines it as:

> **conscious** (*adj.*) having knowledge of something; aware: *we are conscious of the extent of the problem.*